# Bit wise operation in pointer, unsigned char

Tags: c, pointers, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitwise-xor

I am trying to change one bit of an unsigned char variable to 1. I keep getting a segmentation fault though. Here is the code fragment that fails:

```
    unsigned char bitvector[16];


int addbit(unsigned char *bitv,int bit){ 
    int a = bit/CHAR_BIT; //part of char array we want. CHAR_BIT is 8
    bitv[a] |= 1 <<bit; 
    return 1
}
```

...

```
if(checkbit(pointer->bitvector,i)==0){
//checkbit works great! bitv[0] has the value of 71, 
//a turns to be 0 when I call it
            addbit(pointer->bitvector,i);
```

Compile:
make: *** [all] Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: can you please show the code where `addbit` is called, including the definition of the arguments?

Comment: `1 << bit` is wrong, but wouldn't segfault

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I ll try to reproduce the problem in a minimal example, you are right

Comment: Needs `% CHAR_BIT` somewhere.

Comment: Your code fragment fails to compile because you don't have a semicolon on `return 1`. Obviously your real code does have that semicolon -- which demonstrates that you haven't shown us your real code. Show us your real code. (Copy-and-paste it, don't retype it.)

Comment: Seriously -- read the article klutt linked ([MCVE]; just click on any of the words). It goes into detail about how to make one. Just follow the instructions there.

Answer (score 1):

As your question is not clear, I made the assumption you wanted to change the bit n of a word of (16x8bits). Here is a working example :

```
#define     CHAR_BIT 8

int addbit(unsigned char *bitv,int bit)
{ 
    int a = bit/CHAR_BIT; //part of char array we want. CHAR_BIT is 8
    bitv[a] |= 1 <<(bit%CHAR_BIT); 
    return 1;
}


int main()
{
    unsigned char bitvector[16]={0};    
    addbit(bitvector,9);
    for (int i=0;i<16;i++)
        printf ("%x ",bitvector[i]);        
}
```

It displays: 0 2 0 0 0 0 ...

Answer (score 1):

Segmentation fault indicates that you are doing something in a memory area that you haven't allocated. A typical reason is that your `i` is too large and you try to access memory beyond the allocated area referenced by `bitv` pointer. Another common reason is that you have already freed the memory.

Also, you should change `1 << bit` to `1 << (bit % 8)`. Otherwise e.g. `addbit(ptr, 9)` would lead to bit number 9 at bitv[1]. The bit will be set, but the value gets truncated at the assignation.

Comment: great tip about the shift command. thank you, I ll put it in my project

Answer (score -1):

As it turns out, the problem was on the proper initialization of the bitvector. As for the bitwise operator bitv[a] |= 1 <

Comment: What does this mean? `bitv[a] |= 1 < ` is only a fragment of a C statement (in a fragment of a sentence). And "proper initialization of the bitvector"? It is not at all clear from your question or your self-answer what the problem was or how it was solved. You never provided a [MCVE] for your question. Please  remember that one of the purposes of Stack Overflow is to provide searchable questions with answers that are complete and which can help those who find the question, not just those who pose the question. Would this seem like a good answer to you if the answer was unknown?